# Why did my account get reset after I changed my username on Geometry Dash?

Tags: geometry-dash

My account got reset and I have to start from scratch to get back to where I was... I lost my stuff such as Diamonds, Mana Orbs, Stars; Heck even Coins! I loved when I had defeated 2 demons and was going good till I wanted to change my username to something more appropriate to my designs and aspects... Sadly I no longer have ANYTHING that was once mine. Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does creating an account reset your progress?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/297705/does-creating-an-account-reset-your-progress)

Comment: @mindstormsboi Are creating accounts and changing usernames synchronous enough to be considered duplicates?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Its the same old solution every time account data "dissapears". You just click save and then load.

Answer (score 1):

## Save

Before logging out of your account, always go to accounts and click save account. This will back it up. This is why when you log out, you get a big warning telling you that your local data will be deleted. If you don’t save its gone.

## Log Out/Unlink

When your name is changed you are refreshing your login (not the same). You can also log out manually. You will get a warning telling you your data could be deleted.

## Refresh Login

You shouldn’t be affected on a refresh.

## Load

Go to accounts and click load.

## How to Fix your Issue

Try clicking “load” in accounts. If that doesn’t work, and you have no other devices with the data on it, you are done. Your data has been lost, then, sadly.